# Difference between SmsStatus and MessageStatus from Twilio Callback POST

Tags: twilio

I set up a callback URL for Twilio to POST the status of the outbound message. 
However, when I inspect the URL, I find these two parameters:

"SmsStatus" and "MessageStatus"

They seemed exactly the same to me, as the values of the two are always the same. And as I went through the documentation of Twilio website, I could not find any explanation on the difference between these two parameters. Does anyone know the difference?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe this is backwards compatibility for an older version of the API when it just supplied SMS messages (thus `SmsStatus`). Now that the API refers to SMS and MMS messages, the parameter `MessageStatus` was introduced, though they do match each other, as you have noticed.

For future proofing your work, I would recommend using the `MessageStatus` parameter as that refers to the most recent part of the API.

Comment: Thank you! It's very helpful.

Comment: No problem! I'll be around StackOverflow if there's anything else you need help with!

Comment: Thans Phil, so for inbound messages we should only use SmsStatus? (MessageStatus appears not be included)

Comment: @david-giorgi do you mean the request made when you receive an inbound message? If so, you shouldn't need a status parameter at all for that (and [there isn't one documented](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application)) since you have now received the message. For use with status callback webhooks you should use `MessageStatus`.

Comment: Thanks Phil. that makes sense.